I'm having trouble printing lines read from file in C
I have a file named DB.txt, I read lines in a for loop and print those lines out but the ting is nothing prints out. I think it's important to mention that I'm coding in CLion on MAC because there were always some issues when I worked with files (e.g. I tried to write into a file but instead of what I inputed I always got trash in this file33)
so my code now looks like this
int fileInput(struct nn *record){
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("DB.txt", "r");
    char buffer[80];

    if(f == NULL){
        printf(stderr, "Cannot open file");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), f) != NULL) {
            printf("%s", buffer);
        }
//            int j = 0;
//            char *token = strtok(buffer, " ");
//            while(token != NULL){
//                strcpy(record[x].params[j], token);
//                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
//                j++;
//            }
//            x++;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 1;
}

(the commented part is supposed to split the line by spaces and add each string to a struct array, but for now it's irrelevant)
and I just don't get why it doesn't print anything

You are most probably running an old version of the program since this function will not compile in the state you've shown us. See printf(stderr,... and unbalanced {/}.

Another issue you may stumble on (after you've fixed the function so it compiles) would be if the first line in the file is longer than 79 characters.

printf(stderr, "Cannot open file");??? Turn on your compiler warnings and read them.  And always use proper headers.  Your code does have #include <stdio.h> in it?

Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function main and all #include directives, as well as the exact input required to reproduce the problem. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

It is possible that your working directory is not as same as the folder that contains the file DB.txt, since you're reading from a relative path. But you probably missed the error since you're using printf to print out errors instead of fprintf which prints to a file handle (stderr).
You can learn how to set your working directory by referring to another StackOverflow answer here.
